# Как подсветить меню?

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Задача: реализовать возможность скрывать и показывать главное меню по нажатию Alt, а также подсвечивать меню после появления (вроде меню FireFox работает также). Собственно как скрыть/показать я знаю, но вот подсветка меню всегда происходит только по второму нажатию Alt после показа меню. Я пробовал перемещать фокус на menuBar и на конкретное меню, пробовал `menuBar()->actions()[0].hover()`, пробовал `activateWindow()`, `setActiveAction()`, `activate(QAction::Hover)`

Перехватываем сообщение о нажатом Alt

```
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event){
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (ke->key() == Qt::Key_Alt)
        {
            keyReleaseEvent(ke);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return QMainWindow::event(event);
}
```

Обрабатываем Alt

```
void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent (QKeyEvent* event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Alt){
        if (menuBar()->isHidden()){
            menuBar()->show();
            menuBar()->setFocus(Qt::MenuBarFocusEvent); //Здесь пробовал всё вышеперечисленное
        }
        else{
            menuBar()->hide();
        {
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведте код который выполняет указанные функции

Comment: @Cerbo привёл, что-нибудь ещё нужно?

Comment: Мое небольшое исследование показало, что меню подсвечивается весьма хитрым способом. Объект QMenuBar временно регистрирует себя фильтром событий объекта приложения то есть буквально `qApp->installEventFilter(this)`. В этом фильтре он обрабатывает нажатия клавиш (вообще много чего делает) и по Alt входит в режим управления с клавиатуры это, собственно, и означает подсветку. Решением было-бы посылать фиктивное событие о нажатии Alt, но в связи с выше описанной химией непонятно куда слать это событие.

Comment: @Cerbo  спасибо за подсказку, на самом деле нужно посылать два фиктивных сообщения: keyPressed и keyReleased, тогда подсветка срабатывает. В моём случае посылать их нужно в `menuBar()`. Я сделал это так: `QApplication::sendEvent(menuBar(), altPress);` и `QApplication::sendEvent(menuBar(), altRelease);` , где `altPress` и `altRelease` - объекты `QKeyEvent`

Comment: Я это проверил первым делом и не работало. Qt 5.5 на Виндоуз 7 собранный Визульной Студией 2012.

Comment: Если вы нашли решение, пожайлуйста, опубликуйте его в качестве ответа на свой вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Костыльное решение найдено. Для начала нужно удостовериться, что параметр `focusPolicy` всех виджетов имеет значение `Qt::StrongFocus`.

Далее нужно написать свой обработчик переключения фокуса так, чтобы `QMenu` обрабатывались как часть `QMenuBar`

```
void MainWindow::onFocusChanging(QWidget* old, QWidget* now){
    if(now != menuBar() && now != menuBar()->findChild<QMenu*>() && old == menuBar()) {
        menuBar()->hide();
    }
    else{

            QKeyEvent* altPress = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Alt,  Qt::NoModifier);
            QKeyEvent* altRelease = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_Alt, Qt::NoModifier);

            QApplication::sendEvent(menuBar(), altPress);
            QApplication::sendEvent(menuBar(), altRelease);
        }
}
```

и связать его с сигналом `QApplication` о переключении фокуса, я сделал это в прямо в main:

```
QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(focusChanged(QWidget*, QWidget*)), &w, SLOT(onFocusChanging(QWidget*, QWidget*)));
```

Ну а дальше всё как было:

Перехватываем сообщение о нажатом Alt

```
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event){
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (ke->key() == Qt::Key_Alt)
        {
            keyReleaseEvent(ke);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return QMainWindow::event(event);
}
```

Обрабатываем Alt

```
void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent (QKeyEvent* event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Alt){
        if (menuBar()->isHidden()){
            menuBar()->show();
            menuBar()->setFocus(); 
        }
    }
    else menuBar()->hide();
}
```

Надеюсь посмотревшие простят мне столь уродливое решение и плохое описание, но это единственное, что удалось придумать для решения данной задачи.

Comment: А почему не послать фиктивные сообщения сразу после `menuBar()->setFocus()`

Comment: @Cerbo приложение вылетает со StackOverflow, не знаю почему, но при этом также создаётся огромное количество потоков. Возможно это баг Qt